# Get number from a line of a txt file and use it as input to extract lines

Tags: python, string, match, string-matching

the title might sound weird. So I'll do my best to explain the problem.

I have a txt file (generated by another software) that looks like:

```
 EVAPORATION AND TRANSIPIRATION TOTALS     PERIOD    1   STEP    1,   15 COLUMNS,   10 ROWS,  1 LAYERS       ELAPSED TIME 6.0000000E+00           DAYS

    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    1.00000        1.00000        1.00000        1.00000        1.00000        1.00000        1.00000        1.00000        1.00000        1.00000        1.00000        1.00000        1.00000        1.00000        1.00000    


 EVAPORATION AND TRANSIPIRATION TOTALS     PERIOD    1   STEP    2,   15 COLUMNS,   10 ROWS,  1 LAYERS       ELAPSED TIME 1.2000000E+01           DAYS

    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    10.00000        2.00000        2.00000        2.00000        2.00000        7.00000        2.00000        6.00000        6.00000        5.00000        2.00000        3.00000        4.00000        1.00000        0.00000


 EVAPORATION AND TRANSIPIRATION TOTALS     PERIOD    1   STEP    3,   15 COLUMNS,   10 ROWS,  1 LAYERS       ELAPSED TIME 1.8000000E+01           DAYS

    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    2.00000        4.00000        1.00000        2.00000        4.00000        1.00000        3.00000        4.00000        6.00000        8.00000        0.00000        1.00000        2.00000        2.00000        1.00000    
    2.00000        3.00000        2.00000        2.00000        2.00000        5.00000        0.00000        6.00000        1.00000        3.00000        2.00000        3.00000        4.00000        1.00000        0.00000      


 EVAPORATION AND TRANSIPIRATION TOTALS     PERIOD    1   STEP    4,   15 COLUMNS,   10 ROWS,  1 LAYERS       ELAPSED TIME 2.4000000E+01           DAYS

    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000        0.00000    
    3.00000        3.00000        3.00000        3.00000        3.00000        3.00000        3.00000        4.00000        4.00000        3.00000        2.00000        1.00000        0.00000        3.00000        1.00000
```

As you can see it has 2 empty lines (also for the first block, not visible here) 1 line with some text, another empty line and a kind of matrix (and so on).

What I want to do is extract are the **last n lines** from each matrix (from each block) of some **STEP** (given as numbers from the user, for example from STEP 2 to STEP 3)

The n value is given by the **ROWS** number above each matrix. The number is always the same for each block (so in this example I'd like to extract the last 10 rows of the 2nd and 3rd matrix).

I need to put the line-blocks in a dictionary where the key in the **STEP** number (the changes for each block, in this example 2 and 3) and the values are the corresponding last 10 lines (so maybe np arrays as values).

Someone has some suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: From "STEP 2 to STEP 3". Will that always be contiguous?

Comment: @Reti43.. I'd say yes.. the file could be quite big but the STEP interval is always contiguous without any brakes..

Comment: How big do you expect the file to be in MB?

Comment: mmm if MB not over 2-3 MB.. normally I'd say hundreds of KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes that the format of the file is specific (reasonable enough since it's generated by a program). Namely, for each block you two empty lines, a string line, an empty line, and 20 rows of data (24 rows overall).

Since the files are small relative to available memory, you can load the whole file in one go. Then with simple arithmetic you can figure out how many lines to skip to start reading from a specific block. Then, you can pass the next n lines as a generator to [`numpy.genfromtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) which will efficiently and painlessly load them to an array. The only thing to note is that when you read the file with `readlines()`, you keep the newline character with you, which you want to remove when you pass the data to numpy (`line[:-1]`).

```
import numpy as np

def read_data(fname, rows, first_block, last_block):
    with open(fname) as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    blocks = {}
    for block in range(first_block, last_block+1):
        start = 24 * block + 24 - rows
        blocks[block] = np.genfromtxt((line[:-1] for line in data[start:start+rows]), autostrip=True)
    return blocks
```

You can run it like this

```
data = read_data('my_data.txt', 10, 2, 3)
```

and it will return a dictionary of float type arrays. In this case, you'll have `data[2]` and `data[3]`.

Comment: wow.. astonishing simple.. just one specification.. actually the file does not have an header.. It begins with 2 empty line, string line, empty line, block and so on..

Comment: I tried to run your function with a sample file (I edited the file also in the question) but it returns always arrays made by zeros..

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.split()` function to make this easier. It is explained quite well [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm).

I am sure this is not the most efficient way to do it (and any other suggestions will be welcome), but because you know the number of spaces between each value, you can use this to get a list of the values. There seem to be currently 8 spaces between each of the values in the code provided by you. Once you have 
opened your file an stored as `myfile`, for example, if you call

```
file = myfile.split("        ")
```

a list of items is stored in file. This list is basically the whole of `myfile`, but each time you see 8 spaces between two items, this becomes a new item in the file. So, each of your values will be stored as a separate item of this list, since there are 8 spaces between each of them. You will probably need to delete or ignore the first few items of the list as these will include parts of your title which have been split as well. This is a pretty bad explanation but hopefully you can figure it out.

You can use this to write a function to place each block of values in its separate list.

First use this to place each block into a list of lists (a nested list), where each item in the main list is a row of your block (or a column, depending on how you want to access them). The concept is covered [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) if you haven't met it before. So, they will end up like this:

```
step1 = [[0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000...], [0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000...], [0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000...], ...]
```

In this case `step1` will contain 20 lists (each one being a row of the **STEP 1** block), and each list contains 15 values - one for each column of the **STEP 1** block.

If you want access, say, row 3 of your table, you can just type `step1[3]`, and this will give you a list with all the items of row 3 in order, from left to right on your block shown above in your question (for the sake of explaining, I am calling the first (top) *row 0*, the second *row 1*, etc.

If you then want to find the item in row 4, column 3 (calling the first column *column 0*), you can find it as `step1[4][3]`.

Note that I have assigned the rows first, and then nested a the column as lists inside them, as this is slightly easier for extracting whole rows at once, as you wanted to.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. a quick explanation on how to use the ``split`` function will sure help me.. :)